# Iphone - PhoneGap Build failed with 7 errors?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have xCode 3.2.6 and i have installed phonegap cordova 1.7.0 . I followed the read me instruction and installed. After creating the new app using template i run the application. But the build is failed showing some 7 errors.

/Users/xxx/Desktop/testPGAP/build/testPGAP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testPGAP.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh: line 2: touch: command not found

Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copyplist failed with exit code 127

and libCordova.a, cordova.framework , cordovaLibTests.octest and cordovaLibApp.app showing in red color.

What may be the problem. What is the solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: Do you have a list of the errors?

Comment: yes.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127

Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copyplist failed with exit code 127

Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings failed with exit code 127

Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings failed with exit code 127